# How to integrate MongoDB 4.0 with Sitecore 9.1?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to integrate MongoDB 4.0 with Sitecore 9.1 (to collect analytics data) but not sure what and where to change in the configuration files. I followed the steps mentioned in the installation guide but it's not very clear and specific. Have anyone of you tried such a thing recently? If so please let me know. Will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3):

If you see this table, 9.1 is compatible with MongoDb 3.6.6, not 4. (https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/633863).

The guide on setting it up is in the [installation instructions](https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/85019670EECE4D008EEB3AD7037CE456.ashx) for 9.1. The basics are:

1. Enable the `sc.Xdb.Collection.Data.MongoDb.xml.disabled` configuration file by
   removing `.disabled` extension.
2. Disable `sc.Xdb.Collection.Data.Sql.xml` configuration file by adding the .disabled file
   extension.
3. Update the `collection` connection string to point to the MongoDB instance

   You must also update the collection connection string in the indexer job that exists under the following roles:

   - XP Single (XP0): xConnect
   - XP Scaled (XP1): xConnect Collection & xConnect Collection Search
4. Rebuild the xDB search indexes in Solr

That would swap the xConnect collections database from the SQL Server provider to the MongoDB provider. note, this is done on the `xConnect` application

Comment: Thanks for providing the insight. These steps which is exactly the same as mentioned in the installation guide was not very helpful. I will break-down the areas where I have a followup questions:
1. There are two files with same name at (\wwwroot\demo.helixbase.xconnect\App_Data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_data\config\sitecore\Collection) and (\wwwroot\demo.helixbase.xconnect\App_Data\Config\Sitecore\Collection)
I tried changing it at both the places.

Comment: 2. Same named file is again at two locations (wwwroot\demo.helixbase.xconnect\App_Data\Config\Sitecore\Collection) and (\wwwroot\demo.helixbase.xconnect\App_Data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_data\config\sitecore\Collection.
3. By reading this point it seems there is a variable named "collection" (not sure in which file but I presume it would be the file mentioned in the step1) with a connection string value ( a kind of url or path) but there is no such item except <ConnectionStringName>. Also, would be helpful if you can indicate the files referred as "the indexer job".

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to the Sitecore so might be asking something which may look oblivious to others.